# Azure Table/Blob/Queue random Timeout on linux system (k8s .net core 3 app)

Tags: c#, azure, timeout, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

This is my scenario:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob 11.2.0
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue 11.2.0
Micorosoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table 1.0.7
```

I've moved a lot of my code from Azure function to Google k8s and Google Cloud, running the Core .Net app, basically with the same library built in .net Standard 2.0 without any problems.

After a few days, I notice a different behavior in the Linux system.
Few calls interacting with Azure service (blob, table, queue) get timeouts (subsystem appears to fail, i tried different retry-police with same result).
In 10,000 calls I get 10 to 50 errors (or very long calls 180 seconds, before I changed the timeouts). This happens in all Azure services: table, blob and queue.

I tried different solutions to find out why:

- I instantiate the client (blobClient, TableClient..etc) every call, or recycle the same client but without difference
- I change all timeouts to handle this behavior. I work on ServerTimeout and MaximumExecutionTime and put a layer on top, with my retry mechanism, so I can minimize errors. Now I have "only" a few calls of 20 seconds (instead of 2/3 sec for example).
- I tried all solutions with similar problems found on Stackoverflow :D ... but nothing works (for now)

Same dll code run on azure function without any problems.

So i came to the conclusion, there is something in the http client, used internally by the azure sdk, that depends on the operating system you are running your code on.
I think after a few articles it may be the Keep-Alive header, so I try on my composition root:

```
ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive (true, 120000, 10000);
```

but nothing changes.

Any ideas or suggestions? ... maybe I'm on the wrong path, or i've missed something.

Comment: Since you moved to Google cloud, did you check the network latency between the GCP region where your application is deployed and the Azure region where your storage account is?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT Thanks, I'll take a look. Could latency between regions be so important? Some of my calls are blocked for minutes

Comment: It's very important :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to find out any clue about network latency/issue?

Comment: I'm taking your suggestion seriously, I'm trying to figure it out (now for example I'm reading this article https://cloud.google.com/solutions/patterns-for-connecting-other-csps-with-gcp).

But tbho, in my head there is a little voice that whispers "how can a latency be such a disruptive problem? In the worst case there can be some latency on the calls..but hang a call?
I think a lot of people use Azure services from k8s. It seems strange to me not being able to find more problems similar to mine. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: By the way, my google network is europe-west1 / europe-west4 and I use multiple areas in Azure (with backups in different regions Western Europe, Northern Europe and Central France).

Comment: Ok region wise both are in close proximity. Would you mind sharing you storage access code snippet for me to have a look? Also take a look at these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-performance-checklist and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/storage-performance-checklist

Comment: We're having the exact same setup and issue (moved Compute to Google Cloud, but Storage stayed in Azure), with sometimes the Storage calls taking either very long or failing after exactly 180 seconds. 

Our latency from the Google to the Azure datacenter is in the single-digit milliseconds. Azure SQL Database works just fine, it's only Azure Storage that has this problems, and the calls fail after *exactly* 180 seconds for some reason.

Comment: At the risk of a "me too" comment - seeing the same thing on a .NET 5 WebAPI that we're deploying to a Linux WebApp instance in Azure.  For some reason, **any** call to Table Storage, either directly via our own "repository" wrapper, or via our use of an Orleans Client (that is using Table Storage for the cluster config) is either timing out or just simply not even returning from the calls

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE**

After reading the last article linked by @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT in the last comment i tried to change this setting:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

This was the turning point.

Since it used to happen randomly, I'm still not 100% sure if the problem is solved.
But after 50k calls, I'm pretty optimistic. Obviously in production will have another behavior, but I already expect it :)

**UPDATE 2 - AFTER PUBLISH IN PROD**

In the end, it doesn't work :(
I had written in the comments, but it seems fair to update here (more readable).
I still have long calls (abbreviated with MaximumExecutionTime), but I don't see the light at the end of the tunnel.
Now I'm thinking about moving some Azure storage to Google storage, but haven't completely given up.

Comment: Did this actually solve your problem in production? We're having the *exact* same setup and issue (moved Compute to Google Cloud, but Storage stayed in Azure), with sometimes the Storage calls taking either very long or failing after exactly 180 seconds.

AFAIK the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` property doesn't actually *do* anything in .NET Core and is a noop, so I'm really curious why this solved the issue for you.

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm still working on it. Given the lack of interest I thought it was just my problem, due to some strange configuration in my files, so I had stopped updating the info. As soon as I have news I will inform you.